# Notepad++ + fpc compiler

Tags: notepad++, pascal, freepascal, fpc

How to combine Free Pascal compiler and NP++ (or maybe other editor, Vim, Geany, ...)? i.e. I want something like IDE: compiling, running from NP++, list of errors\warnings. I tried http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/331753/topic/2084061?message=5036415 but it doesn't work. Also tried some different code

```
cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
fpc $(NAME_PART).pas
```

but the same issue occurs

[image]

Comment: Why do you want use Notepad++ instead of [Lazarus](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/)?

Comment: It crashes sometimes (OS win7) and I need only console applications, not GUI designer, projects (I not sure because I uninstalled it few weeks ago, but as I can remember I can't just create\open .pas file, I need to create project etc.) and so on.

Comment: FYI you cannot compile directly a .pas file without a project file (lpr).

Comment: RRUZ: with FPC (and TP before it) you can. The FPC compiler itself is a .pp.  Anyway, I would recommend lazarus too, trying to use general editors for such purposes only caused me pain in the past, and in the end they always want you to write a plugin

Comment: Marco van de Voort: but maybe someone already wrote this plugin for any editor like NP++, Geany etc.?:)

Comment: Not that I know. Nearly everybody uses Lazarus. A few (like me) use the textmode IDE that comes with FPC (fp.exe). There used to be a VI syntax highlighter file, and also some XCode stuff, but those are  all very simplistic and crude if you are used to a real IDE. Anyway, +1 for the trouble so you get something out of this :_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, looks like np++ plugin mentioned in the question works, not sure what was the problem and why it did not create .exe when I first tried, but now everything works.

Also found SciTE editor, where it is possible to add something like

```
#using free pascal

# compile
command.compile.*.pas=fpc "$(FilePath)"

# normal execute
if PLAT_WIN
    command.go.*.pas="$(FileName).exe"
    command.go.subsystem.*.pas=2
if PLAT_GTK
    command.go.*.pas="kvt -e $(FileName)"

# build
command.build.*.pas=fpc -B "$(FilePath)"
command.build.subsystem.*.pas=1

command.name.0.*.pas=Debug Compile
command.0.*.pas=fpc -g "$(FilePath)"
command.name.1.*.pas=Debug Build
command.1.*.pas=fpc -g -B "$(FilePath)"
command.name.2.*.pas=GDB
if PLAT_WIN
    command.2.*.pas=gdbpasw "$(FileName)"
if PLAT_GTK
    command.2.*.pas=gdb "$(FileName)"
    command.name.3.*.pas=DDD
    command.3.*.pas=ddd "$(FileName)"
```

to `pascal.properties`. Or here it is already included: http://code.google.com/p/scite-ru/downloads/list

Answer (score 1):

You should try [ConText](http://www.contexteditor.org/). I use it for Pascal programming. It isn't the most beautiful code editor, but I think that for Pascal it is the best. I use the "Turbo Pascal 7.0" highlighter from [there](http://www.contexteditor.org/highlighters/). I have codes for commands like compile, run the .exe or open file in Free Pascal. If you'd like I can write them there.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this script to compile and run the my pascal code:

```
cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
C:\FPC\2.6.0\bin\i386-Win32\fpc.exe $(NAME_PART).pas
$(NAME_PART).exe
```

Remember to change the fpc path if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this code:

```
NPP_SAVE
cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
CMD.EXE /C if exist $(Name_PART).exe DEL $(Name_PART).exe
fpc.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

It is for compiling

Comment: It's an old question, and he said later in an answer that it got solved on it's own